# How can see Google Now flights cards on my LG G2?

Tags: google-now, lg-g2

How can see flights cards on my LG G2? I have Google Search, Google Now Launcher and G+ as well. I was looking at [this](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/39504/android-4-2-using-google-now-to-monitor-your-flights-status/) article on how to activate flight search,  but I don't see these settings on my G2.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

If you've already activated the Fligth's card, then you only have to do a simple search on google. 
You WON'T have a card that let's you search for flights. Instead you'll have a card that remembers you of all the flights you searched. 
For example: if I search a flight with Emirates that goes from Milan to Dubai, then Google Now will keep track of all the flight's info. After I make the search and close the browser, in Google Now there'll be a card that tells me if there are delays, the airport of departure and the airport of arrival and all the other info.
Long story short: there ISN'T a Flights SEARCH card in Google Now; there is a Flights Card and that's different ;)

P.S.: if my answer helped you could you accept it? :)

Comment: "If you've already activated the Fligth's card" Where do I see this? I dont have this in Settings. Any screenshots?

Comment: Open the Google App (the one with the blue icon) -> tap the gear icon in the top left corner. You'll see the cards's settings there. Tell me if it works ;)

Comment: I have Google's app with Blue background that says lower case G. When I click on it, it goes to Google Now. But there is no gear icon on Google Now screen. Settings open when I click on 3 dots and select Settings. But when I click on middle (I guess Magic Wand or soemthing) icon, it opens "Customize google Now" screen. In that screen, I see "Sports", "Stocks", "Places", "TV & video" and "Everything else" options. I dont see flights.